# Performance of getting count of collection in Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, performance, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I'm developing an api in which I will return user A blog post's detail.

So my response from api will be as below:

```
{
BlogDetail : {
   id : 1,
   title : 'My blog',
   ....
   totalComments : 123, //Always present

   //Add comments based on user parameter getComment in api -- If true append else dont 

   comments : [{
      user : 'Steve Smith',
      comment ; 'Virat learn from me how to bat in test cricket'
   },
   ....]


},
..... //Other Fields
}
```

Blog Schema: It **wont have totalComments** field in schema.

```
 {
   _id : 1,
   title: 'xyz',
   ....
 }
```

Comment schema :

```
{
   _id : 1,
   blog_id: 1,
   user : 'abc',
   comment: 'xyz'
   ....
 }
```

Here Blog Detail & Comments are stored in Blogs and Comments collections respectively.

Based on user parameter I will append Comments in response. But will always return total number of comments on that post.

Now my question is :

1 How to join two collection in `mongoose`?

2 As per MongoDB `db.collection.count()` and `db.collection.find().count()` are equal. So it will scan through all the documents? So its better to use `db.collection.find()` and store it some where so I can letter use them?

How to improve performance?

Answer (score 1):

check [lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup) in aggregate

````
```
BlogDetail.aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
        from: "Comments",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "Comments",
        as: "Comments"
    }
}]).exec(function(err, students) {
    // do whatever you want
});
```
````

Comment: Try populate in mongoose, but you need to add comments reference to blogdetails when saving.